# How to use list comprehension in the following case?

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

I have a text file which has names of the universities. I want to clean this dataset - remove whitespaces and empty lines. I have achieved this with the following code. However, is there an efficient way of achieving this? May be using List Comprehensions?

Code:

````
txtfile = open('university_towns.txt', 'r')
lines = txtfile.readlines()
txtfile.close()

#Removing empty lines and whitespaces
new_lines = []
for line in lines:
    if not re.match(r'^\s*$', line):
        new_lines.append(line.strip())
lines = new_lines.copy()```
````

Comment: What is *inefficient about this*? Yes, you can trivially turn this into a list comprehension, but that really has nothing to do with efficiency

Comment: One thing that would make this more efficient is not to use `readlines` and just loop over the file object directly, so you dont need an intermediate list. Again, this could be done with a list comprehension, but that is not really relevant to the efficiency

Comment: You're right. I compared to check the runtime of the two approaches, found not much difference. Thank you Juanpa.arrivillaga!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code with list comprehension.

```
with open('university_towns.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if not re.match(r'^\s*$', line)]
```

Comment: And you don't need regex here, just do `if line.strip()`

Comment: Well this is no more efficient. Why use readlines? Just loop over the file object directly for efficiency